# Centering div in another div with image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this structure:
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
  <div class="circle">
    X
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

I want to place div with class circle **exactly** in the center of div "wrapper", on the given image. Is it possible to do this in css only? if not, the solution can use jQuery.

I have many divs in diffrent sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just absolutely position the div and place it in the center. As long as the values are hardcoded just push it into the center. Make sure to add `position: relative` to the wrapper so that the circle gets absolutely positioned inside the wrapper and not a div above it in the tree.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    /* other vals */
    position: relative;
}

.circle {
    /* other vals */
    position: absolute;
    left: /* (width of wrapper - width of circle)/2 */
    top: /* (height of wrapper - height of circle)/2 */
}
```

Comment: .wrapper .circle { left: 50% top: 50% margin-left: /* -(width of circle / 2 ) / margin-top: / -(height of circle / 2 ) */ } Now values are not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Soluton 1:

```
.wrapper {
     position: relative;
}


.circle {
     position: absolute;
     trnasform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

Soluton 2:

```
 .wrapper .circle {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
 }
```

Solution 3:

This already exists - http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

This will help you allign your div vertically and horizontally in the middle.